Looking for title of old Star Trek TOS book where Spock is captured and gets earring
Two decades ago I read a lot of the old TOS novels. There was one novel where Spock was captured (on a planet iirc) and made prisoner of a female person/ alien. She equipped him with accessories like an earring or piercing, maybe even a collar. It felt a lot like an author self-insert. Spock even rationalized most of her decisions or demands, thinking they or his compliance were logical. What was the name of the book?

Black Fire by Sonni Cooper
Google Preview.

The jewelry he had been made to wear was carefully chosen even to the earring in his right ear. He recalled the placement of the earring by Ilsa; it was then that he first experienced the full force of the restraining beam, which had held him immobile as she pierced his ear with a large awl and set the shining stone in place.


Yup, seems most likely. I haven't read it, but reviews generally find it to be a series of poorly-rationalized sexy Spock vignettes held together by a barely-there plot. Spock also orchestrates a prison escape and becomes a renowned space pirate.

Original source (archive.org copy): https://archive.org/details/blackfirestartre00sonn/page/56/mode/2up

Pre-Internet Spock fanfiction is a good way to summarize the book, I guess. That is indeed the book in question and you even found the paragraph where he gets his earring! Very impressive and thanks a lot!

My guess - "The Pandora Principle" by Carolyn Clowes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pandora_Principle

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There's nothing in the link you provide that shows how it matches the question.  Can you include any quotes or otherwise explain how it fits?

No, this is not the one, but thanks for the suggestion.
